# Asynchronous request-reply with Spring Boot and RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

We want to implement the following scenario:

1. A producer service sends some input params to another service asking for the details based on these params.
2. A producer wants to specify the queue where it will be listening for the reply.
3. Moreover, a producer wants to provide some metadata so that it can correlate the params it sent with a result it got.

Please advice how to do this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [AsyncRabbitTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#async-template).

It uses the correlationId and replyTo properties to convey that information to the service that handles the request.